# Image on plane as particle hairs - Shadow problem

Tags: materials, particles, shadows

I'm trying to create grass by using images on a plane and then using those in a hair particle system. However in some areas I'm seeing the shadow from the plane instead of the grass itself.

**Grass Object Template**

[image: Grass Object Template]

**Template Material Settings**

[image: Template Material Settings]

**Rendered Hair Particles**

[image: Rendered Hair Particles]

**Another Sample: You can see that some of the shadows are correct while others are using the plane's shadow**

[image: Another Sample]

Comment: I did manage to remove a lot of the problem by increasing `Render Properties -> Light Paths -> Transparency` but it seems overkill for something that just shouldn't be there to begin with.

Comment: Is this Cycles or EEVEE?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard: the material snapshot show "blend mode" - so i would assume it is EEVEE